# Show if $f(x)=x^4+2x^2+2$ is injective or surjective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$f(x)=x^4+2x^2+2$$
Is it injective:  $$x^4+2x^2+2=0$$
$$x^2=u $$
$$u^2+2u+2=0 $$
$$u_{1,2}=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{-4}}{2}$$
Doesn't have a real root.

We can also try another way to see if it is injective: $$f^{-1}(f(x))=\text{identity of domain}$$
$$x=y^4+2y^2+2 = (y^2+1)^2+1$$
when we solve for y we get:

$$\pm\sqrt{\pm\sqrt{x-1}-1}=f^{-1}(x)$$

So this means we can do the following:

$$f^{-1}(f(x))=\pm\sqrt{\pm\sqrt{x^4+2x^2+1}-1}$$

I have a feeling that something went wrong here. I later also need to show for surjectivity(in lectures we have shown this way:$f(f^{-1}(x)=\text{identity of range}$). But it stops here.

Comment: what's the domain of $f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not injective; $f(-1) = f(1) = 4$.

It's also not surjective; $f(x) = (x^2+1)^2 + 1 \geq 1$ so it takes no negative values.

Answer (score 2):

As a map from $\mathbb R $ to itself it is neither injective nor surjective.  It is not injective because $f(-x)=f(x)$; it is not surjective becasue $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. In particular $f(x) \neq -1$ for any $x$.